# Verify a matrix value on MATLAB 2

Tags: matlab, matrix

- I am using MATLAB. I have a question about how i can verify that the values of a matrix are being repeating, like this:

A=[ 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3]
with the answer AUX=1

If the matrix A repeat at least the first two values for all columns after, i want a AUX = 1. but if not, only AUX= 0.

or 
A=[ 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2]
with the answer AUX=1

If the matrix A repeat like before, i want a AUX = 1. but if not, only AUX= 0.

- The matrix A can also have zeros numbers after the numbers. (example, A = [ 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0], A = [ 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 0 0 0 ].)

Comment: Do you want the zeros to be excluded from the comparison? That is, should `A = [ 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0]` give `aux = 1`?

Comment: I don't want @LuisMendo.

Comment: Is a second problem of that @Dan

Comment: @OscarSantacruz Then use first part of my answer

Comment: But what is the difference? What's the new part of the question??

Comment: Yes, the A = [2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2] @Dan

Comment: Just use the same code as Colin Bowers provided before but adjust it for pattern of length 4 instead of just 2.

Comment: Its not very clear, but I assumed that [1 2 1 2 2 1] should also return true in this new question.

Comment: Can you give a few examples in which the result should be 0?

Comment: Only when the results are A = [ 1 2 1 2 1 2] or A = [ 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3] must be 1, in otherwise 0. @LuisMendo

Comment: How about `A = [ 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]`? Or `A = [ 1 2 3 0 1 2 3]`? You need to explain _clearly_ what you want

Comment: AUX = 0 on those cases. @LuisMendo

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this, finding whether the same two numbers are used in each non overlapping window of 2 values:

```
% Cutting off the tail
x = [1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 0 0];
x = x(1:find(x,1,'last'));
x = x(1:2*fix(numel(x)/2));

% Checking for allowed values (the first 2 values, each one once)
M=sort(reshape(x,2,[]));
AUX = size(unique(M','rows'),1)==1
```

Note that this cuts of trailing zeros, so you may need an extra step if the number of remaining elements is not always odd but that should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

% A
A = [1 2 3 4 4 5; 1 3 4 5 6 5; 6 7 4 1 3 3];
% make A a column vector
A_col = A(:);
% calculate histogram of A with max(A_col) bins
n = hist(A_col, max(A_col));
AUX = sum(n > 1) > 0